# Almost there... Need to find and replace. Using for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to find and replace. I am using a for loop. I am learning but I am almost there. I have tried to find the answer but the sources have been a bit too confusing for me.

The delim is a blank space and as you can tell I am skipping 4 lines and doing the 2nd token.

I need what is found there at that spot to be replaced by **var5a**. I have it backwards, as I need **%%F** to equal **var5a**, not the other way around (as I have it written now). But don't know how to write it. Please explain how one can do this. I've tried using <<= but with no luck.

```
for /f "skip=4 tokens=2 delims= " %%F in (script.vbs) do (
set var5a=!var5a!%%F
)
```

I'm learning so please be kind.

Comment: You'd be *much* better off writing *anything* like this in VBScript.  Or Powershell.  Or Perl.  *ANYTHING* but .bat files.  IMHO...

Comment: I am more familiar with batch atm. thank you.

Comment: paulsm How do I exchange the variables in batch with VBScript? I have all my variables in batch but how do I transfer them to a vbscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Replace token 2 (space-separated) in line 5 of a file with REPLACEMENT
:: Assumed the file exists, etc. and no line begins ":"
SET replacement=THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT TEXT
DEL newfile.txt 2>nul
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN ('findstr /n /r "$" ^<oldfile.txt') DO (
IF %%i==5 (
FOR /f "tokens=1,2* delims= " %%L IN ("%%j") DO >>newfile.txt ECHO %%L %replacement% %%N
) ELSE (>>newfile.txt ECHO.%%j)
)

TYPE oldfile.txt
ECHO ==== separator =======
FC oldfile.txt newfile.txt
```

Results:

```
Line one should not be changed
Line two should not be changed
Line three should not be changed
Line four should not be changed
changeme iwillbereplaced but only on this line
and notbereplaced on subsequent lines

including the previous line which was empty
==== separator =======
Comparing files oldfile.txt and NEWFILE.TXT
***** oldfile.txt
Line four should not be changed
changeme iwillbereplaced but only on this line
and notbereplaced on subsequent lines
***** NEWFILE.TXT
Line four should not be changed
changeme THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT TEXT but only on this line
and notbereplaced on subsequent lines
*****
```

There are difficulties - especially if the lines in your file start with a colon or contain quoted-strings or any of the usual batch gotchas like `%`

---

So - at long last I've worked out what you're doing. You omitted the critical information that the string in `%%F` is not only quoted, it also contains spaces.

Had you said that in the first place, you'd be hours further into your project, and I'd be richer by a handful of aspirin.

In order to load %%F with a quoted string, I've read the string from a file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
:: Replace token 2 (space-separated) in line 5 of a file with REPLACEMENT
:: Assumed the file exists, etc. and no line begins ":"
SET replacement="THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT TEXT"
DEL newfile.txt 2>NUL

:: iwbr.txt just contains
:: "i will be replaced"
:: on a single line for loading into %%F as that is the target to be replaced


FOR /f "delims=" %%F IN (iwbr.txt) DO (
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i IN (
  'findstr /n /r "$" ^<oldfile.txt'
 ) DO >>newfile.txt (
  IF %%i==5 (
   SET newline=%%j
   CALL SET newline=%%newline:%%F=%replacement%%%
    ECHO.!newline!
  ) ELSE (ECHO.%%j)
  )
)
TYPE oldfile.txt
ECHO ==== separator =======
FC oldfile.txt newfile.txt
```

Results:

```
Line one should not be changed
Line two should not be changed
Line three "should" not be changed
Line four should not be changed
changeme "i will bereplaced" but only on this line
and notbereplaced on subsequent lines

including the "previous" line which was empty
including this "unbalanced-quote line...
==== separator =======
Comparing files oldfile.txt and NEWFILE.TXT
***** oldfile.txt
Line four should not be changed
changeme "i will bereplaced" but only on this line
and notbereplaced on subsequent lines
***** NEWFILE.TXT
Line four should not be changed
changeme "THIS IS THE REPLACEMENT TEXT" but only on this line
and notbereplaced on subsequent lines
*****
```

Comment: I replaced oldfile.txt with script.vbs and then made `set replacement=!var5a!`

Comment: The variable %%F does contain quoted string. How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

If you have `Henri` in %%F and you want to set the value of `Henri` to the current value of `var5a` then

```
set %%F=!var5a!
```

(**!var5a!** if you want the RUN-TIME value of `var5a` (provided you have ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION mode invoked) or **%var5a%** if you want the PARSE-TIME value)

---

Program to demonstrate that the answer does work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::: WARNING! This will overwrite SCRIPT.VBS

DEL script.vbs 2>nul
FOR /l %%i IN (1,1,4) DO >>script.vbs ECHO ignore this line %%i
>>script.vbs ECHO Oh Henri - it does work
>>script.vbs ECHO Now try again

ECHO ===== here is script.vbs

TYPE script.vbs

ECHO ===== script.vbs ends

SET var5a=this is the value

SET henri
SET var5a

ECHO ===== now run the FOR loop...

for /f "skip=4 tokens=2 delims= " %%F in (script.vbs) do (
 set %%F=!var5a!
)

SET henri

GOTO :eof
```

Results:

```
===== here is script.vbs
ignore this line 1
ignore this line 2
ignore this line 3
ignore this line 4
Oh Henri - it does work
Now try again
===== script.vbs ends
Environment variable henri not defined
var5a=this is the value
===== now run the FOR loop...
Henri=this is the value
```

Now - what do you mean by `"it doesn't work"`? It certainly does. If it's not doing what you want it to do, then demonstrate WHY you make the claim, otherwise we're left guessing.

For instance, the above will also set `try` to the value because `Henri` isn't the ONLY token that's number 2, space-delimited after 4 lines of the source file. That's easy to fix (but I'm not a mindreader - just a humble programmer)

```
(set notsetyet=Y)
for /f "skip=4 tokens=2 delims= " %%F in (script.vbs) do (
 IF DEFINED NOTSETYET set %%F=!var5a!&(set notsetyet=)
)
```

But maybe `"it didn't work"` because it `Henri` was set to the wrong value. Or perhaps it crashed. We can't tell from your response.

Comment: It doesn't work because the value of %%F is always different. It is could be Henri, David or even Jesus. How do I do that?

Comment: So how do we know what variabl you want to set to what value? You haven't given a clear example of what you mean, just that you have `"it"` backwards and then you say `"I need %%F to equal var5a"` so - exemplify. Suppose %%F is has a value of `xyz` and `var5a` has a value of `abc` - what do you want to happen?

Comment: According to your example: I'd like `xyz` to be replaced by `abc` in script.vbs. On the fifth line in the second token using spaces as delims. Does that make sense? I'd like the value of var5a to replace %%F in script.vbs exactly where I say %%F is located in script.vbs.